# GitHub action is running older versions of workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I am creating a workflow and have successfully published it to the marketplace

But when I want to use it in my main project it seems to can the older version

```
      - name: Call trello-github-actions
        id: trello
        uses: maliyo/github-action-integration@1.1.5
        with:
          action: test_case
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN_TRELLO }}
          TRELLO_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.TRELLO_API_KEY }}
```

1.1.5 is the current version but it runs code from version 1.1.2

[image: it is set to be the latest release]

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to run `npm run build` to rebuild the index.js file